# Syntax Error while implementing LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, slim-3

I have following `PHP` serving me data by executing `SQL` on `MARIADB`.

```
function getData ($countsql, $datasql, $page, $limit, $input, $response){
    try{
        $offset = ($page-1) * $limit; //calculate what data you want

        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
        $countQuery = $db->prepare( $countsql );
        $dataQuery = $db->prepare( $datasql );
        $dataQuery->bindParam(':limit', $limit, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $dataQuery->bindParam(':offset', $offset, \PDO::PARAM_INT);

        while(sizeof($input)){
            $curr = array_pop($input);
            $dataQuery->bindParam($curr["key"], $curr["keyvalue"]);
            $countQuery->bindParam($curr["key"], $curr["keyvalue"]);
        }


        echo $datasql."+";
        echo $limit."+";
        echo $offset;


        $dataQuery->execute();
        $countQuery->execute();
        $db = null; // clear db object
        $count = $countQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $data  = $dataQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($count['COUNT']>0&&count($data)){
            $data_arr=array();

            $data_arr["records"]=array();
            $data_arr["pagination"]=array();

            $data_arr["records"] = $data;
            $data_arr["pagination"] =   array(
                                                "count" => (int)$count['COUNT'],
                                                "page" => $page,
                                                "limit" => $limit,
                                                "totalpages" => ceil($count['COUNT']/$limit)
                                            );


       return $response->withJson($data_arr,200); 
        }
        else{
            return $response->withJson  (
                                            array("msg" => "Nothing found."),
                                            204
                                        );
        }
    }catch( PDOException $e ) {
        //return '{"error": {"msg":' . $e->getMessage() . '}';
        return $response->withJson  (
                                        array("msg" => $e->getMessage()),
                                        500
                                    );
    } 
}
```

Problem is when i am executing this on my local `MARIADB` server, code is working fine, but when i am executing it online server, its producing following error (Note that I printed the SQL+limit+offset in the end for debug)

```
{"msg":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''999999' OFFSET 0' at line 1"}SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ART WHERE ART.AUTHOR_ID = AUTHOR.ID) as COUNT FROM AUTHOR LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset+999999+0
```

Is there a error in syntax or version mismatch?

**EDIT**

I would also like to ask one little thing,

Is this a correct way to get COUNT

```
SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ART WHERE ART.AUTHOR_ID = AUTHOR.ID) as COUNT FROM AUTHOR
```

Or should i join these two tables and then compute the same?

Comment: Perhaps MariaDB does not allow quotes around the number in `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough PHP to answer the first part of your question, but here is the raw MySQL query I would use:

```
SELECT
    AU.*,
    COALESCE(AR.CNT, 0) AS COUNT
FROM AUTHOR AU
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT AUTHOR_ID, COUNT(*) AS CNT
    FROM ART
    GROUP BY AUTHOR_ID
) AR
    ON AU.ID = AR.AUTHOR_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification. You seem to know well about SQL. I was reading about implementing [`pagination`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pagination-optimization/) and `MARIADB` suggested to get rid of `offset` and use `id` and `limit` instead. Can you suggest me some good references for optimal pagination?

Comment: That is the best ref, but I am biased.